# SOAP Parsing in windows phone 7

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

I will searching since 10 days but i have not succeed in soap parsing in wp7.

My code is below. I get the The remote server returned an error: NotFound. and System.Net.WebException.

code is below :

```
 private const string AuthServiceUri = "http://manarws.org/WS/manarService.asmx";
    private const string AuthEnvelope =
                       @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
                        <soap:Body>
                            <fnGetNewsResponse xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">
                               <fnGetNewsResult></fnGetNewsResult>
                               </fnGetNewsResponse>                
                        </soap:Body>
                    </soap:Envelope>";

 public void Authenticate()
    {
        HttpWebRequest spAuthReq = HttpWebRequest.Create(AuthServiceUri) as HttpWebRequest;
        spAuthReq.Headers["SOAPAction"] = "http://tempuri.org/fnGetNews";
        spAuthReq.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
        spAuthReq.Method = "POST";
        spAuthReq.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(spAuthReqCallBack), spAuthReq);
    }

 private void spAuthReqCallBack(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("REquest is :" + request.Headers);
        Stream _body = request.EndGetRequestStream(asyncResult);
        string envelope = string.Format(AuthEnvelope,"","");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Envelope is :" + envelope);
        byte[] formBytes = encoding.GetBytes(envelope);
        _body.Write(formBytes, 0, formBytes.Length);
        _body.Close();
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ResponseCallback), request);
    }

 private void ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Async Result is :" + asyncResult);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Response is :::::::::::::::::::----" + request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult));

        if (request != null && response != null)
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```

I get the error in `HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);` line...

So, Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps to know how to use a SOAP service

```
-- Create a new project.
-- Right-click on the Project name and click on "Add Service Reference"...
   Then provide address as "http://manarws.org/WS/manarService.asmx?wsdl" and click Go.
-- Once service information is downloaded, provide Namespace something like
   "MyMemberService" at the bottom and click Ok.
```

Now that your proxy classes should be ready.
Go to your Mainpage.xaml.cs and type 'client' there..you should probably get a class with the name "ManarServiceClient".

If you get that, then try to call the suitable methods of that class.

For an example,

```
ManarServiceClient client = new ManarServiceClient();
client.fnGetNewsResponseCompleted += new EventHandler<fnGetNewsResponseCompletedEventArgs>(client_fnGetNewsResponseCompleted);
client.fnGetNewsResponseAsync();
```

Note: I am not with my working system, so cannot give you exact code. All the above is a guessed code and shall point you in the right direction. Will test my code and update soon.

Comment: Adding http://manarws.org/WS/manarService.asmx or http://manarws.org/WS/manarService.asmx?wsdl ??

Comment: Thank you for your great support. it is done in another windows machine.

Comment: hi, please tell me how to parse this webservie ? manarws.org/WS/manarService.asmx?op=fnGetMoreProductPhotos That is a parameter so how to send parameter to webservice ?

Comment: How to pass a parameter ?? inside the soap request

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me how to pass parameters in soap request ?

Comment: I have answered your other question .. please check that. I hope it solves your problem. Sorry for the delay !!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I am missing something but why not just adding a service reference ?

The service located at 'http://manarws.org/WS/manarService.asmx' is a classic web service and you can browse wsdl. You can add a reference in Visual Studio. It will generate a proxy class to call this webservice. Manual soap parsing is quite painful.

**EDIT :**

1) Right clic on service reference in your project.

[image: step1]

2) Enter your service url. Then click Go.

[image: step2]

3) You will have new classes in your project.

Just use them as you want. Exemple :

```
public void GetBranches()
{
    ManarServiceReference.manarServiceSoapClient client = new ManarServiceReference.manarServiceSoapClient();
    client.fnGetBranchesCompleted += new EventHandler<ManarServiceReference.fnGetBranchesCompletedEventArgs>(client_fnGetBranchesCompleted);
    client.fnGetBranchesAsync();
}

void client_fnGetBranchesCompleted(object sender, ManarServiceReference.fnGetBranchesCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //TODO
}
```

Comment: please put the code here i m confused bcz i m new in windows phone 7 developement. Thanks.

Comment: but it is giving me exception like Endpoint not found was unhandeled.

Comment: The Response is in the form of json. i just print the result in client_fnGetBranchesCompleted() like e.Result at that point i get above exception.

Comment: quite unclear. Are you adding the reference in the app or in a library ? could you edit you question and add the error message.

Comment: The Exception look likes                                       There was no endpoint listening at http://manarws.org/WS/manarService.asmx that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException,   if present, for more details.                                                            And the Detail is System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFound Exception.

Comment: no probems from my side, I can call the "test" service. I think you have not understand my previous question. Are you adding the reference in the target app OR in a separete class libray (because some config have to be present in the target app).

Comment: Please give me your mail id i can send my code. I get the EndPointNotFound Exception. with above code you paste.

Comment: I'd prefer to get it with a direct download link or with skydrive folder.

Comment: Please give me your mail id i will upload it on dropbox.

Comment: @Rishi join this [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17226/windows-phone-7-8), we will discuss the problem

Comment: hi, please tell me how to parse this webservie ? http://manarws.org/WS/manarService.asmx?op=fnGetMoreProductPhotos  That is a parameter so how to send parameter to webservice ?

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me how to pass parameters in soap service ?

Answer (score 0):

If you create of an asmx web service. The first call is incredibly slow.