# How to Pass parameters in SOAP request in wp7

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

I have done with the simple SOAP parsing in wp7 with adding reference of SOAP Service in my application.

but i don't understand how to pass parameters in soap request ?

my SOAP Service is this

```
http://www.manarws.org/ws/manarService.asmx?op=fnGetSubCertificate
```

with the Certificate id is : 8

i have search about this last 5 days but don't get any way to do this.

Please help me.

Comment: Well I just opened your service with the wcftestclient and I am invoking the method fnGetCertificate() which receive a request of type fnGetCertificateRequest, and this request has a property body of type fnGetCertificateRequestBody, here I am trying to expand this object but I don't see any property where to supply the certificate Id

Comment: Please open above link and inside soap request 1.2 the parameter is there. i will parse fnGetCertificate() already. but no idea about fnGetSubCertificate() how to pass parameter ?

Comment: well, this what I see http://i.stack.imgur.com/glH0x.png
the thing is you are receiving a request object, but this request does not have any property where to set your ID, I think your should change your service contracts and add that field to your fnGetCertificateRequestBody object

Comment: i need to parse this http://www.manarws.org/ws/manarService.asmx?op=fnGetSubCertificate inside this how to pass parameter like       <certificateId>string</certificateId>

Comment: this is my main service which i was add as a refrence http://www.manarws.org/ws/manarService.asmx

Comment: Ok, well let me post you some code, I will do it in a webproject because I dont have the wp sdk, just hold on...

Comment: Please check my previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781775/soap-parsing-in-windows-phone-7   inside this nkChandra's answer is right. and i can sucessfully parsed the fnGetBranches() method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20029/discussion-between-luis-laurent-and-rishi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the service reference for your project, as I explained in the previous SO post:

You can make the web request like this and pass the parameters.

```
manarServiceSoapClient client = new manarServiceSoapClient();
client.fnGetSubCertificateCompleted += client_fnGetSubCertificateCompleted;
client.fnGetSubCertificateAsync("8");
```

And the response is obtained in the Completed handler

```
void client_fnGetSubCertificateCompleted(object sender, fnGetSubCertificateCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var resp = e.Result;
    }
```

I got response like this

```
[{"ArTitle":"مركز السمع والكلام ","EnTitle":"Hearing & Speech Center ","PhotosCatsId ...
//Removed the rest
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. and i get the solution for that also. you answer is totally true. I get the response both way like this and creating soap envelope also. Thanks.